# Find divisors and store them in array

Tags: c

I have written the following code which contans two functions

1.To find the number of divisors of a number

2.To store the divisors in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numOfDivisors(int n)
{
    int i, numOfDivisors=0;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            numOfDivisors++;
        }
    }
    return numOfDivisors;
}

void storeDivisors(int count,int divisors[],int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1,j=0;i<=n,j<count;i++,j++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            divisors[j]=i;
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int n,m,a,i;

    scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&m,&a);

    int count1=numOfDivisors(n);
    int count2=numOfDivisors(m);

    /*printf("%d %d",count1,count2);*/

    int divisors1[count1],divisors2[count2];

    storeDivisors(count1,divisors1,n);
    storeDivisors(count2,divisors2,m);

    for(i=0;i<count1;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%d\n",divisors1[i],divisors2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is just part of a bigger code I need to make.

I am getting junk values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am getting junk values. What am I doing wrong?

If `count2` is less than `count1`, `divisors2` does not have as many values and you end up accessing the array out of bounds.

Print the two divisors separately.

```
for(i=0;i<count1;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",divisors1[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<count2;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",divisors2[i]);
}
```

Also, as was pointed out by @BLUEPIXY, you have an indexing error in `storeDivisiors`.

Instead of

```
for(i=1,j=0;i<=n,j<count;i++,j++)
{
    if(n%i==0)
    {
        divisors[j]=i;
    }
}
```

use

```
for(i=1,j=0;i<=n,j<count;i++)
{
    if(n%i==0)
    {
        divisors[j++]=i;
        //       ^^^^ increment j only when storing a divisor.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop in your `storeDivisors()` function is wrong.  In it, variable `j` appears intended to represent the index in the `divisors` array where the next divisor should be stored, but in that case you should increment it only when you in fact store a divisor.  Instead, you increment it at every iteration.  You will end up with some `divisors[]` positions containing junk values, and not all divisors being stored.

The loop should look like this:

```
int i,j;
for(i=1,j=0;i<=n,j<count;i++)
{
    if(n%i==0)
    {
        divisors[j++]=i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in :

```
for(i=1,j=0;i<=n,j<count;i++,j++)
{
    if(n%i==0)
    {
        divisors[j]=i;
    }
}
```

`j` is always equal to `i-1`. Consequently, most of items in array `divisor` will never be set.

Try :

```
for(i=1,j=0;i<=n,j<count;i++)
{
    if(n%i==0)
    {
        divisors[j]=i;
        j++;
    }
}
```

That way, `j` increases if, and only if, a divisor is found.

The next step is to use dynamic memory allocation, to avoid computing the divisors twice and use a "resizable" array. The function [`realloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) of stdlib may inspire you. To avoid reallocating the array each time a new divisor is found, a structure similar to a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) will be needed. See [How to replicate vector in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694401/how-to-replicate-vector-in-c) or [Converting C++ implementation of vector in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992299/converting-c-implementation-of-vector-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here, I have gotten better since the past few days and intend to improve my above code.

I have eliminated the need to make a function to find the number of divisors of `n` since that is immaterial in storing the divisors in an array. I have improved my `storeDivisors` function which not only stores all the divisors but if needed will also give the count of divisors. Here is the updated code --

```
#include <stdio.h>

void storeDivisors(int n,int a[],int *x)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
            a[(*x)++]=i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 100;
    int a[100];
    int x = 0;
    int i;

    storeDivisors(n,a,&x);

    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    printf("number of divisors = %d\n",x);

    return 0;
}
```