# Declaring array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an array

```
int arr*;
```

I have declared a struct

```
struct counter{
    int index=0;
    int count=0;
    int *values;  // array
}
```

and the array will have a predefined max size.

How do I "push" structs inside each index of array? I have tried to do as following:

```
for ( int i =0; i < max ; i ++ ){
    arr[i]=counter Store_Struct;
    arr[i]->values=(int *)malloc ( 2 * sizeof ( int ));
}
```

but this little piece of code didn't work. How can I push structures as array values?

Comment: Please consider restricting your questions to code that will at least pass the compiler, or else to questions about why the compiler rejects the code.  Yours is neither.

Comment: `int arr*;` won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

"Pushing" isn't supported; neither by the standard library nor by any built-in. You'll need to write your own [dynamic memory allocation mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992299/converting-c-implementation-of-vector-in-c) instead.

Also, C doesn't support default initialization of `struct` members like what you are attempting to use. Use a [designated initializer list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).